# ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 System.Net.Http.HttpClient Extremely Slow on First Request

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await

Something as simple as this, on the first request, takes 25 to 30 seconds to make a request to my api running locally.

```
    private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register()
    {
        var result = await Client.GetAsync("http://localhost:50823/api/business");
        var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var businesses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<<List<Business>>>(response);

        return View(businesses);
    }
```

This is a .net core mvc application calling a .net core api application. Both are .net core 1.0.1, I do plan on upgrading to 2.0 but it looks to be quite the process so I haven't done it yet. I am not sure why the call `Client.GetAsync` takes an extreme amount of time on the first request, and then it's milliseconds on subsequent. Also if I make a few requests to this action, then wait a few minutes and do it again, it's back to being extremely slow on that first request, then fast again. I have no idea why this is happening and have tried just about everything I can find on the internet.

Comment: why do you think the problem in the client? it may be the server. also I'd check via Fiddler that request does take all that time.

Comment: What service is listening?

Comment: @Shrike I'm certain it's the client, using a rest client (advanced rest client for chrome) I can hit the api just fine and never have to wait more than a few milliseconds. the service is local host - both running via visual studio debug, however, this is acting the same way in production hosted via iis as well as hosting in local iis.

Comment: @Ofiris local host service which is .net core api